# Merge with duplicates values in R

Tags: r, join, merge, duplicates

I have two dataframes

db1 like :

```
date.prix;var1;var2
2012-10-02;pluf;plof
2012-12-11;pam;pim
2013-05-17;plop;plip
...
```

db2 like :

```
date.de.cotation;var3;var4
2012-10-02;tutu;toto
2012-10-02;ting;tong
2013-05-17;gui;guou
...
```

The join is date.prix = date.de.cotation

And I want something like :

```
date.prix;var1;var2;var3;var4
2012-10-02;pluf;plof;tutu;toto
2012-12-11;pam;pim;NA;NA
2013-05-17;plop;plip;gui;guou
```

So :

- if there are duplicates in db2, I want values of the first
- if there is no value for the date in db2, I want NAs

Comment: Delete duplicates from `db2` and merge `db1` with `db2` using `all.x = T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

left-join in `data.table` has a `mult` parameter: `mult='first'` will only reserve first matching row in `db2`.

```
library(data.table)

db1 <- fread('date.prix;var1;var2
2012-10-02;pluf;plof
2012-12-11;pam;pim
2013-05-17;plop;plip')

db2 <- fread('date.de.cotation;var3;var4
2012-10-02;tutu;toto
2012-10-02;ting;tong
2013-05-17;gui;guou')

# if db1 and db2 are not data.table, do: setDT(db1); setDT(db2);

db2[db1, on = .(date.de.cotation = date.prix), mult = 'first']
#    date.de.cotation var3 var4 var1 var2
# 1:       2012-10-02 tutu toto pluf plof
# 2:       2012-12-11   NA   NA  pam  pim
# 3:       2013-05-17  gui guou plop plip
```

Comment: There is an error with this command :  `Error in [.data.frame(base.concurrence2016, base.platts2016, on = .(date.de.cotation = date.prix),  : 
  unused arguments (on = .(date.de.cotation = date.prix), mult = "first")`

Comment: @celianou, as I said in comment of the above code, you should convert `db1` and `db2` to `data.table` first if they are `data.frame` with `setDT(db1); setDT(db2)`

Answer (score 2):

We can use the [`duplicated`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/duplicated.html) and [`merge`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html) functions:

```
db2_2 <- db2[!duplicated(db2$date.de.cotation), ] # remove everything but first instance
merge(db1, db2_2, by.x = 'date.prix', by.y = 'date.de.cotation', all.x = TRUE)

#    date.prix var1 var2 var3 var4
# 1 2012-10-02 pluf plof tutu toto
# 2 2012-12-11  pam  pim <NA> <NA>
# 3 2013-05-17 plop plip  gui guou
```